# How to run an init python script whenever a python/ipython kernel is launched?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a python script that import my regular functions and it would great to be able to automatically run whenever a python or ipython kernel is launched. 
So I do not have to import every time.

Comment: well, there's the deprecated [`user`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/user.html) module.  I'll let you decide if the deprecation means if this is a good idea or not

Comment: I just put my commands in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.py`

Comment: You could use the environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP

Comment: [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) is the way to go if you want to do the same thing in IPython and the regular Python shell. For just IPython, you can save any .py file in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`.